# Combing Two jQuery Objects To Make One Custom Context for Efficient Selectors

Tags: jquery

I have some common elements that are in a #footer and #header divs respectively.
In order to make the selectors faster, I'd like to make a custom jquery object.

A combination of #footer and #header. Something like:

```
var someCustomContext = $("#footer") + $("#header");
var betterQuickerSelector = $(".buttonClass", someCustomContext);
```

Is this possible?

Thanks SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine selectors with commas:

```
var someCustomContext = $("#footer, #header");
```

Or if you have already got two separate jQuery objects you can combine them with the [`.add()` method](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
var footer = $("#footer"),
    header = $("#header"),
    combined = footer.add(header);
```

`.add()` also works with selectors:

```
combined = footer.add("#header");
```

...and some other options as described on the doco page.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate any number of selectors with commas:

```
var someCustomContext = $('#footer, #header');
```

Or for already existing selectors you can do:

```
var $header = $('#header'),
    $footer = $('#footer'),
    someCustomContext = $header.add($footer);
```